# New segments no longer available in API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, segments

For a long time I'm using advanced segments created in GA in my API calls. I never experienced any trouble with this. However since last week new created segments don't show up in the management API. I checked it with several profiles, but new segments just won't show up. I have thought maybe there is a limit, but when I remove some segments and add some new, they still don't show up. They also don't show up at the Query explorer http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Does anyone have experience with this and have a solution?

Comment: Are you sure its the right user your checking under?  I just tested it mine show up.

Comment: Just found the solution.

You can set the filter on trafic sources to Visitor or User. When you select User, the segment will not be available in de API. If you select Visitor it will.

Comment: could you please share the link?

Comment: There's no direct link, it's in the Analytics Advanced settings when you create or edit a segment.

Answer (score 0):

This is because [new segmentation features](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/07/re-imagining-segmentation-in-analytics.html) were added this past July, and they are not currently supported in the API.

So if you segment on users using the new segments UI in the Web Interface, the segments won't show up when listing in the Management API, and they won't work with the Core Reporting API. However, session/visitor segments with conditions continue to work. This is why you're seeing this behavior...until the API has full support for this.

You can review the Management API changelog, [Release 2013-07-15](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/changelog) for exact details on this.

You should subscribe to the changelog so you'll be notified if support is added.